# How to open G.L.O.B.E. DEM files from NOAA

Tags: arcmap, dem, elevation, globe, maxar-digitalglobe

I need to open a free GLOBE DEM. I have downloaded some tiles from: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/gltiles.html, but I don't know which software should I use in order to open those files. Is ArcMap able to view those files ?

Comment: So according to the documentation, the G.L.O.B.E DEM files are "16-bit signed integer data in a simple binary raster". These do not have associated header files so you will likely have to make your own. There are links here to help you open the data depending on what software/system you have: https://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/mgg/topo/report/s11/

Comment: Seems like an old dataset why not use the SRTM which you can download from Earth Explorer website, georeferenced and ready for GIS?